# Tika parsers configuration in SpringBoot

Tags: java, gradle, apache-tika

I'm using a tika parsers in my project. 
I'm using three classes from this package:

```
org.apache.tika.Tika;
org.apache.tika.parser.txt.CharsetDetector;
org.apache.tika.parser.txt.CharsetMatch;
```

Last time I rised an version from Tika 1.0 to Tika 1.20.
Then it started to throwing warnings like:

```
WARN  org.apache.tika.parser.SQLite3Parser : org.xerial's sqlite-jdbc is not loaded.
Please provide the jar on your classpath to parse sqlite files.
See tika-parsers/pom.xml for the correct version.
```

I don't need these dependencies in my app so I tried to avoid it in following ways:
0. Created an tika-config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
  <service-loader initializableProblemHandler="ignore"/>
</properties>
```

1. Added to application.yaml tika.config property with relative and not-relative path to tika-config.xml file. Didn't worked.
2. Added an TIKA_CONFIG enviroment variable. Also didn't worked.

Is there any other solution that can I try to get rid of these warnings?

Comment: and how do you read tika-config.xml in your code?

Comment: Try that config:

`
<properties>
   <service-loader loadErrorHandler="IGNORE"/>
</properties>
`

Comment: @The_Cute_Hedgehog tried, didn't work. Also in meanwhile tried to exclude these parsers.

Comment: @Karim, tika config is read by default Tika. new Tika() uses default TikaConfig which should read file from tika.properties, or if it doesn't exist, from TIKA_CONFIG env. variable.

Comment: can you try this? to make sure it reads the correct config not the default one
TikaConfig config = new TikaConfig("/path/to/tika-config.xml");
Detector detector = config.getDetector();
Parser autoDetectParser = new AutoDetectParser(config);

Comment: I tried that right now. At beginning I tried with relative path and it throwed NoSuchFileException. Then I used not-relative path and now it passed test (TikaConfig properly initialized), but still showing these warnings. I don't use Tika in other parts of code. May it be used by another dependency, implicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason you have this warning is because the sqlite is no longer embeded with tika jar
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/tika/SQLite%20Parser

try exluding sql with this, or add sqlite dependency

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
  <parsers>
    <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser">
      <mime-exclude>application/sql</mime-exclude>
    </parser>
  </parsers>
</properties>
```

if you want to add sqlite dependency

add this to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
  <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.10.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Tried with property and env. variable.

Comment: <service-loader loadErrorHandler="IGNORE"/> add this to the config